# Launching python.exe in eclipse using PyDev causes exception

Tags: python, eclipse, jython-2.7

I am using the PyDev plugin with a Jython2.7.0 interpreter.  In my code I attempt to execute the following code:

```
import subprocess
subp = subprocess.Popen('C:\Python27\python.exe')
```

The eclipse console shows the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site.py", line 68, in <module>
    import os
  File "C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\os.py", line 432, in <module>
    import UserDict
  File "C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\UserDict.py", line 83, in <module>
    import _abcoll
  File "C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\_abcoll.py", line 11, in <module>
    from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
  File "C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\abc.py", line 8, in <module>
    from _weakrefset import WeakSet
  File "C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\_weakrefset.py", line 5, in <module>
    from java.util import WeakHashMap
ImportError: No module named java.util
```

Things I have tried so far include

1. Open calc.exe instead of python.exe.  When I substituted calc.exe I did not get any exception and calc.exe opened up:

   subp = subprocess.Popen('calc.exe')
2. Tried executing the original code outside of eclipse by launching Jython from the windows command prompt.  When I executed the code this way, a python process was opened and there were no errors.

UPDATE:  I have come to realize this issue is stemming from trying to launch python.exe with a "bad" PYTHONPATH.  As I said above, I am running the code using a Jython interpreter in eclipse, and eclipse is managing the PYTHONPATH.  I was able to replicate the exception just by copying the PYTHONPATH supplied by eclipse to my system PYTHONPATH and launching python.exe.  So now I just have to figure out what the PYTHONPATH should be in order to run a Jython script that opens python.

Comment: What about if you try to open jython.exe from the Popen?

Comment: I executed  
    import subprocess
    subp = subprocess.Popen('C:\\jython2.7.0\\bin\\jython.exe')
    subp.kill()
    print "done"

and this executed fine.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the problem had to do with the PYTHONPATH.  I'm not sure which entry in this path was causing Python to break but I ended up changing the code to use the -E option with Python (ignore all environment variables) and it fixed the problem.

```
import subprocess
subp = subprocess.Popen('C:\Python27\python.exe -E')
```